# alignment blocks in width

Tags: css

please help to align blocks of articles so that the width of the extreme elements of the row glued to the edges of the parent koneynera (usually online stores thus arranged goods).

[here](http://prozaik.16mb.com/html5_2/lizt2/) I realized what I want. but in safari and ie9 layout breaks ((

[the same](http://jsfiddle.net/6RdZh/), but in jsfiddle, if you will be so comfortable

important that the articles were not aligned through the float, but through inline-block

css:

```
.reviews_inner .list{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 -20px;

    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}   

    .reviews_inner .list .article{
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 460px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 20px 16px;

        vertical-align: top;
    }

        .reviews_inner .list .article .left{
            float: left;
            width: 108px;
        }

            .reviews_inner .list .article .left .outer{
                width: 100px;
            }

                .reviews_inner .list .article .left .outer img{
                    display: block;
                }

        .reviews_inner .list .article .right{
            float: right;
            width: 342px;

            text-align: left;
        }   

            .reviews_inner .list .article .right .author{
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font: 23px arial, sans-serif;

                display: inline;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }

            .reviews_inner .list .article .right .city{
                font: 23px arial, sans-serif;
            }               

            .reviews_inner .list .article .right p{
                font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with your width

Make your

```
.wrapped {
width:980x;
}
```

However, I really do not like that solution. But this should give you some hints on how to progress on this more. The total horizontal width is more than available ...